# Are there cases where cache line alignment is counter productive?

Tags: c++, caching, optimization, intel, memory-alignment

Most of my work targets a rather narrow set of hardware we have control over (last couple gens of Intel CPUs specifically), and it stays in-house, so we don't have architectural compatibility constraints or issues, and code that needs to be close to the metal and reasonably optimized tends to be not super long lived (months to a couple years tops).

I was wondering the following: Are there any cases that aren't contrived and artificial where managing data so it's always cache line aligned is actually counter productive? On recent Intel CPUs at least.
And more specifically, if there are any, do any apply to SIMD friendly, many PODs cases?

As for why the question:
One of the habits I've developed that's always turned out positive insofar is to plan and control data, especially cases where we have many small POD like objects, so it's cache line aligned and ideally easy to switch around SoA/AoS as needed. This is based on the assumption that it won't hurt. I'm wondering if that assumption is actually a reasonably healthy one to start from though; I couldn't think of any likely enough cases where it'd backfire.

Comment: The biggest drawback I can think of is if your data "grows" suffiiciently from adding emptyness for aligning, that you are filling the cache quicker, and using unaligned data structures would be more cache-efficient. In other words, when you align a 16 byte structure to a 32 byte cache-line, only half as many will fit in the cache, with no real benefit (24 -> 32 would also have the same effect, but with 25% overhead)

Comment: Also - when you traverse your data sequentially, you're progressing much faster in terms of lines consumed per cycle, increasing your memory BW (with useless traffic), and even rendering your HW prefetchers less effective.

Comment: Fair enough about consumption, probably should have added to the question something about cases beside the bigger footprint and the obvious side effects of exceeding cache boundaries sooner. I guess I was more specifically hoping to see if anybody knew of some less obvious cases, or maybe even some hidden gem about out-of-alignment load and store tricks kicking in with some positive side effects. I guess if I haven't found anything about it insofar it's because it'd be too good to be true :)